# Scolling panel in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a layout that uses nested flex boxes, the outer felxbox gives me header content are and footer, in the content area i have a second flexbox that gives me left right and center panels. I want to make the center panel scroll when overflowing. 
I have this working in IE but not chrome, rather then spend many more hours.
 I was hopping someone knows how to do this, thanks. 
Here is my attempt.

https://jsfiddle.net/grw3tLwt/

```
       html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #outer-box {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-flow: column;
        flex-flow: column;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
    }


        #outer-box header {
            -ms-flex: 0 0 100px;
            flex: 0 0 100px;
            background-color: #333;
            background-image: url('/images/bgheader.png');
            background-size: cover;
            color: white;
        }

        #outer-box footer {
            -ms-flex: 0 0 100px;
            flex: 0 0 100px;
            background-color: #333;
            color: white;
        }

        #outer-box #content-box {
            -ms-flex: 1 0 1px;
            flex: 1 0 1px;
        }

            #outer-box #content-box #inner-box {
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -ms-flex-flow: row;
                flex-flow: row;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

        #outer-box #inner-box nav, #outer-box #inner-box aside {
            -ms-flex: 0 0 200px;
            flex: 0 0 200px;
        }

        #outer-box #inner-box div {
            -ms-flex: 0 0 200px;
            flex: 0 0 200px;
            background-color: silver;
        }

        #outer-box #inner-box main {
            -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            max-height: 100%;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

<section id="outer-box">
    <header>
        header
    </header>
    <section id="content-box">
        <section id="inner-box">
            <div>left</div>
            <main>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
                <h2>main</h2>
            </main>
            <div>right</div>
        </section>
    </section>
    <footer>
        footer
    </footer>
</section>
```

Comment: try this..I had just tried if want some more change then tell me https://jsfiddle.net/grw3tLwt/1/

Comment: Thanks Deb, but that puts a fixed height on the main panel, this defeats the idea of having the flexbox, it should scroll on all screens. Thanks